# Magento 2 - Composer require "extension" installation error

Tags: extensions, composer, magento2.3.4

Can't able to install extension using composer, [image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to install **Git Bash** - It is a source control management system for Windows. **Bash** is a Linux-based command line (that has been ported over to Windows).

For more detail, please refer to the [link](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-install-git-bash-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Install git on your centos.
To install the git use below command.

1. sudo dnf update -y
2. sudo dnf install git - y